# Auto smooth does not render

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I have made a corridor with smooth edges. The model has autosmooth aplied (30 degrees) and for som reason when I render it, the auto smooth is not visible.
Viewport:
[image: Viewport]

Render:
[image]